# Net Users, Net View, tracert/nslookup

Tags: cmd, ip-address

I used Net user to get all the user names in the network, and I can get all the computer names with net view. I can get IP of the computer names with nslookup. How do I link the user name with the computername/IP? The goal is to get a list of users on which machine and it's IP address.
Thanks in advance. I've been looking but no luck.
-gemmo

Comment: How did you use `net user` to get all the user names *in the network*? I only know that you can use it to get all the local users or all the domain users.

Comment: @AndriyM you're probably correct, yes domain users, most probably active domain users. In any case, that's probably what I need, as I'm just searching for my immediate team sitting on my floor

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, although actually that makes your original question a bit less clear (to me anyway). Are you talking about distinguishing between domain users and local users in the list returned by `net user`? Could you just illustrate your problem with an example of the output of `net user` and that of `net view` just to point out the issue you are trying to resolve? You could limit the number of items and replace real names with fictitious if necessary, I'd just like to understand better what you are struggling to do.

Comment: Sorry, I was talking rubbish: of course, `net user` displays only local users, and to get the domain users (*only*, too) you'd need to add the `/domain` switch. Still, that doesn't help my understanding of the issue and I'd still welcome an example or just further explanation.

Comment: net view = //L7S0JY3NTY1 gives me a list of machines. net user /domain = XE1WXP gives me a list of users in the domain. so I can get IP of machines, but doesn't tell me which related user name is on the machine.